# How to get information how doctrine query was build

Tags: sql, symfony-1.4, dql, doctrine-1.2

I use doctrine 1.2, in symfony 1.4.8 . Here is my code:

```
private function getWithMaxProductsQ($limit){
    $query = Doctrine_Query::create()
                            ->select('m.name, COUNT(p.manufacturer_id) AS c')
                            ->from('manufacturer m')
                            ->innerJoin('m.Product p')
                            ->where('p.is_published = 1')
                            ->addWhere('p.is_available = 1')
                            ->groupBy('p.manufacturer_id')
                            ->orderBy('c DESC')
                            ->limit($limit);
    //die($query->getSqlQuery());
    return $query;
}
public function getManufacturersForCategoryDeep(Category $cat, $limit = 7){
    $ids = $cat->getDescendantsAndMeIds();
    $q = $this->getWithMaxProductsQ($limit);
    $q->innerJoin('p.Category c')->whereIn('c.id', $ids);

    die($q->getSqlQuery());
    $mans = $q->execute();
    return $mans;
}
```

As you may notice there is `die` call inside `getManufacturersForCategoryDeep` which gives me info what query will be executed. Here is sql query:

```
SELECT `m`.`id` AS `m__id`, `m`.`name` AS `m__name`, COUNT(`p`.`manufacturer_id`) AS `p__0` FROM `manufacturer` `m` 
INNER JOIN `product` `p` ON `m`.`id` = `p`.`manufacturer_id` 
INNER JOIN `category` `c` ON `p`.`category_id` = `c`.`id` 
WHERE `m`.`id` IN ('49', '43', '127', '42', '65', '134', '113') 
AND (`p`.`is_published` = 1 
AND `p`.`is_available` = 1 
AND `c`.`id` IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)) 
GROUP BY `p`.`manufacturer_id` ORDER BY `p__0` DESC
```

And I dont know why this line appear in query `WHERE m.id IN ('49', '43', '127', '42', '65', '134', '113')` 
I used apc and memcached caching for DQL query parsing caching, but it was disabled a month ago. So how i can find out what is happening with this query ?

**UPDATE:** this line is dissapears after removal `limit()` invocation

**UPDATE2:** here is open bug http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DC-1052?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activity-stream-issue-tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add `limit()` to a query in DQL Doctrine actually breaks your query into two separate ones. In the first query only primary keys are selected using all the condition you have used (also the `LIMIT`).

The second query selects the actual objects using the list of the primary keys found in the first one to limit the results. That's why you can see the additional line in your query.

I believe this is used because of performance reasons.

Comment: You mean doctrine make two separate sql requests ? well, than its strange because symfony 1.4 debug bar dont show first query that you mentioned

Comment: Look carefully and you'll find it ;) (At least I can find them in my debug bar). Unless it's Sf 1.4.8 that doesn't log it. Try moving to the latest 1.4.20.

Comment: Someone added this as a bug but I don't think it is one. Even in the query added in the Doctrine ticket you have the additional `WHERE ... IN ...` so it works.

Comment: And BTW - one more reason (or the main reason?) why Doctrine doesn't just use the `LIMIT` clause is that it does not work in every `SQL`.

Comment: you mean there is sql solutinons which doesn`t know about `LIMIT` statement ?

Comment: For example T-SQL, used by MS SQL server.